# Can you run RO filtered water directly into a refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, water-filtration

After having the same fridge for 20 years, I need to buy a new one, and I'm looking at a model that has a water and ice dispenser. I know that this kind of fridge has a water line connection and its own filtering system, but I already have a RO system that makes really good water and I don't need the fridge to process it any further.

Can you run filtered water into the fridge and simply not use the filtering capability of the fridge itself?

Comment: Are you worried your water will be over filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing (or bypassing) the filter inside the fridge could be tricky.

Nothing wrong using both,.

Your RO supplies water to the fridge.

The fridge filter does not do much after that.

They are not so good as your RO, they are only single stage.

The question you have to solve: Is your RO supplying enough pressure and flow.

Comment: How do I know if the pressure is high enough?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank minimum30 psi

Comment: Thanks. I can work with that!

Comment: @JoshuaFrank did you like my answer and comments ?

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the exact model of fridge you buy, but in my experience, not using the filtering capability of a fridge is easy. If you remove (or don't install) the filter cartridge in a fridge with water dispenser/ice maker, there's a valve which bypasses the filter connection.

Comment: Even if there isn't a filter bypass, simply let the water run through the filter housing without a filter in it....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and if you need some ideas there are add-on kits for that.

https://www.123filter.com/ac/index.php?rt=product/product&product_id=10054